# Read variables from javascript in selenium

Tags: javascript, variables, selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver 2.0. Html page being tested, includes x.js file and the variable "price" is defined in x.js based on some data entered from the html form and some calculations on the javascript. HTML prints the right value of price using:
`<td>$ <span id="price"></span></td>`
How can I catch the value of a price from the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the price is displayed as text inside of `<span></span>`, try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("price")).getText();
```

Comment: Actually, this assumption is not the case. The tag is as you see and is the HTML renderer that brings the value.

Comment: And where exactly does it "bring" the value to? Whatever is displayed by your browser can be found somewhere in the HTML source code. I don't see any price value in your example `<td>$ <span id="price"></span></td>`

Comment: Hi, i'm actually using Selenium 1 now that I took a closer look. The span element is populated with a value by a javascript. I've used the wait functionality without success to try to wait for the element "price" to contain a value before proceeding with an assertion.